# What does "GQ" mean in this scholarly context?

Tags: acronyms

I searched the acronym but it apparently stands for all sorts of phrases. Here's the context:

> Imāmīs also claim that the Sunnīs omitted or suppressed Sūrat
>   al-Nūrayn, “The Two Lights”; cf. Ar. text and trans. in Nöldeke, ***GQ***,
>   ii, 102-7) as well as other passages that testify to 'Alī’s distinct
>   role as Muhammad’s spiritual and political heir.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the English language, but an abbreviation used in a scholarly reference. A quick Google search reveals that it is an abbreviation (apparently quite common and standard, within the field) of Theodor Nöldeke’s [_Geschichte des Qorāns_](https://archive.org/details/geschichtedesqor00nluoft) from 1919.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The work is either too well-known to be given in full, or your excerpt has just missed the full reference:

> **Th. Nöldeke's *Geschichte des Qorāns* (1860)**

Comment: now that's astute!